# UIScrollView spin probability

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

In my code, I spin a `UIScrollView` this way:

```
[carousel scrollByNumberOfItems:-35 duration:10.7550f];

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.7550f 
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(randomFinal)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:NO];
```

And in this part, after the scrollView stops, it will do a random movement, either UP or Down:

```
-(void)randomFinal {

    randomBut = arc4random()%5;

    if (randomBut == 0){
 [carousel scrollByNumberOfItems: -1 duration: 4.50f];  
    } else if ( randomBut == 1){
 [carousel scrollByNumberOfItems: 1 duration: 4.50f];  
    } else if (randomBut == 2) {
 [carousel scrollByNumberOfItems: 1 duration: 5.0f];
    } else if (randomBut == 3) {
 [carousel scrollByNumberOfItems: -1 duration: 5.0f];
   } else if (randomBut == 4) {
 [carousel scrollByNumberOfItems:0 duration:0];
    }
}
```

What I need is to make the `randomFinal` part to happen with a percentage of 30% probability. How can I do it? thankyou.

Comment: can you please be a bit more specific? Do you want randomFinal to be called 33% of the the time?

Comment: Yes. you're right I want the randomFinal to happen 33% everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
// arc4random_uniform() returns uniformly distributed random number < than upper_bound.
randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(100 + 1);
if(randomNumber <= 30)
    do something;
```

The random number that results from the call to arc4random_uniform() should be <= 30, 30% of the time.

Comment: Im not following. Your original post said you wanted to execute your method 30% of the time. If you now want it to occur 70% of the time simply change the 30 in the example I gave to 70 and replace "do something" with your call to [NSTimer:]

Answer (score 0):

Well you could write something like:

```
int shouldCallFinal = arc4random()%100;

if(shouldCallFinal <= 70)
{
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.7550f 
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(randomFinal)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:NO]; 
}
```

Comment: how to make this into 70% `[carousel scrollByNumberOfItems:-35 duration:10.7550f];`

Comment: I have edited the answer so randomFinal is is now called 70% of the time

Comment: OK, It sounds like that might be a different question then? But basically it is the same solution; The place where you call scrollByNumberOfItems you decide if you want to call the method based on random number. The same way as suggested in my answer.